# Pegar click do botão na toolbar

Tags: android

Tenho dois botões **Salvar** e **Gravar** na minha toolbar.
Eu não estou conseguindo fazer o click. 
Se eu colocar o click do botão na view normal eu consigo pegar o click

```
private class btGravar implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSalvar:

                String nomeDesc = nome.getText().toString();
                String foneDesc = fone.getText().toString();
                String emailDesc = email.getText().toString();
                String ruaDesc = rua.getText().toString();
```

Será que alguém consegue me ajudar ?

Comment: Defina "[..] não estou conseguindo fazer o click." O que acontece? Nada? Por favor seja mais claro.

Comment: Eai @Genos. Verdade cara. Me desculpa. Acabei esquecendo mesmo. Os dois botões eu quero um salvar e o outro cancelar e voltar para tela anterior. Já coloco no código. Valeu

Answer (score 1):

Faça dessa forma pra pegar os clicks da ToolBar:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.btnSalvar) {

        String nomeDesc = nome.getText().toString();
        String foneDesc = fone.getText().toString();
        String emailDesc = email.getText().toString();
        String ruaDesc = rua.getText().toString();

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Não deu certo Leonardo. Ele dá erro. FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Como você está colocando seu menu no layout? É um xml inflado? Ele está na pasta res/menu?

Comment: Não. To inflando do res/layout activity_cad_cliente.

Comment: O menu está no mesmo arquivo de layout? Não tem um xml próprio do menu?

Comment: Tem sim. o xml do menu está em res/menu. Ma já to inflando ele no layout. Ele já aparece, porém o click ainda não está acontecendo.